# How to create System DSN for Oracle Driver programmatically in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odbc

I need to create a System DSN for Oracle ODBC driver(32 bit) with following information, but this should done programmatically in VB.net.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create ODBC DSN using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447495/create-odbc-dsn-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

ODBC DSN are defined in the Registry. Check branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC` and write according entries in there.